# Auto-completion of LaTeX References in VS Code (Latex-Workshop)

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I found a small issue after moving to using latex-workshop in VS Code instead of a dedicated Tex IDE (have used Texmaker and Texstudio previously).

Specifically, I have some custom defined commands, and the arguments of these commands do not retrieve the auto-complete options that I would expect.

For example, for a given `\label{eg:label}`, a corresponding `\ref{eg...` would bring up a list of previously assigned labels. However, if that `\ref` is contained within a command then it won't find anything. An example like `\newcommand{\exampleref}[1]{Example Reference \ref{#1}}` which, when typing `\exampleref{eg...` does not bring up anything now that the reference command is embedded in a command.

I could not find a way to do this in VS Code, but in Texstudio I would have made a custom .cwl file as per this answer to the [same problem for that IDE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585485). It would just have a single line for that above example command `\exampleref{label%ref}#r.`

Any latex-workshops users that have come across this problem and found a way around it? Closest I have found is some documentation on making a whole package for the commands, which seems somewhat overkill.